# How to repeat openeing tabs?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
times_to_repeat = 10
while times_to_repeat > 0:
    import string
    import random
    S = 6
    ran = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=S))
    x = ran
    print("The randomly generated string is : " + str(ran))
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open("prnt.sc/" + x)
    times_to_repeat -= 1
```

I'm trying to do the prnt.sc challenge, and I want to be able to open 10 tabs of random strings, to speed up the process. My problem is that it only opens one tab when I run it, but it prints my random string ten times. Both are on a loop, so shouldn't both things repeat? I get "your random string is (whatever the string is) 10 times, but my browser only opens 1 tab. I'm quite new to python so I don't know a whole lot about loops.

Comment: I tried your code and is opening 10 browsers for me (with one tab on each). I understand that in your case is just opening the browser one time also?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code seems to be opening 10 different browsers.

I'm not absolutely sure about how but seems that the internal call of  `webbrowser.open("prnt.sc/" + x)` is making the OS don't be able to use the currently active browser, since `prnt.sc/` is not a web URL, because the `https://` part is missing.

Just add the protocol and it will work:

```
while times_to_repeat > 0:
    import string
    import random
    S = 6
    ran = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=S))
    x = ran
    print("The randomly generated string is : " + str(ran))
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open("https://prnt.sc/" + x)
    times_to_repeat -= 1
```

Nevertheless, your code loop is a bit strange and a bit difficult to read. Also, importing libraries on a while loop is not a really good practice.

```
import string
import random
import webbrowser
S = 6

times_to_repeat = 4
for x in range(0, times_to_repeat):
    ran = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, S))
    print("The randomly generated string is : " + str(ran))
    webbrowser.open("https://prnt.sc/" + ran)
```